# AJAX fetching data from Spring-MVC Controller

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

[image]
My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "jobs")
public void removeJobs(@RequestParam("username") String username, Model model) {
   String []jobs = jobsFetcher(username);
   model.addAttribute("list", jobs); 
}
```

My Jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="<c:url value="public/files/styles/jobManager.css" />" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(username) {
    var xmlhttpReq = crossBrowserAjaxObject();
    if (xmlhttpReq) {
        xmlhttpReq.open("get", "jobs", true);
        xmlhttpReq.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse(xmlhttpReq);
        xmlhttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
                'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttpReq.send("username=" + username);
    }
}

function crossBrowserAjaxObject() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function handleServerResponse(xmlhttpReq) {
    //var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return function() {
        alert(xmlhttpReq.readyState);
        if (xmlhttpReq.readyState == 4 && xmlhttpReq.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttpReq.responseText); // this is ok
            // HERE HOW DO I GET THE MODEL OBJECT AS A RESPONSE COMMING FROM SERVLET &
            // USE IN MY JSP FILE ?
        }
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="leftDiv">
        <a href="#" onclick="ajaxFunction('JAMES')">JAMES</a> 
        <a href="#" onclick="ajaxFunction('David')">David</a> 
        <a href="#" onclick="ajaxFunction('Catrina')">Catrina</a> 
        <a href="#" onclick="ajaxFunction('Cathy')">Cathy</a> 
        <a href="#" onclick="ajaxFunction('Paul')">Paul</a>
    </div>

    <div class="rightDiv">
        <!-- HOW DO I GET THE JOB LIST & USE IT HERE USING MY AJAX ? -->
        <c:forEach items="???" var="task">
            <p>${task}</p>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now As I have mentioned inside the picture, I want my right div element change when I click the employees without refreshing the whole page.

the only thing which I don't know is when the xmlhttpReq.responseText returns to me, how I'm gonna fetch the modelelement which does carry an Array of jobs using Ajax & use it to render the page...

in another words how I will be able to fetch the parameters coming from my controller after Ajax call & use Ajax itself to make my page ?

Do you any Idea or suggestion or something that can help me go through this ?

( By The way These codes are not yet tested! )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at jquery it makes ajax requests rather simpler.

You need to change the controller method to include the annotation `@responsebody` on return type. Don't add stuff to the model for ajax requests, it won't work unless you return a new ModelAndView .

[here is an intro](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)

Comment: I saw that, looks good & helpful but It didn't cover my main question. I want to knoe how to use model attribute coming from the controller after an ajax request & use it inside the jsp page ?

Comment: you can't use the model with ajax requests, unless you return a new model and view (which opens a new page). Which kinda defeats the point of ajax in the first place.

Comment: Can you explain more or show me any specification that cover everything in relation between AJAX & Servlet ?

Comment: You can absolutely return a model with an ajax request.  It depends on how you structure your views.  For example, you can return a view that represents an html "chunk" and that is bound to a model object.

Answer (score 4):

Spring MVC 3 and JQuery is one of the great combination to perform the ajax request and response. You need this jar "jackson-mapper-asl".Define the removeJobs controller which handles the Ajax request and return the json response. @ResponseBody converts the custom object into equivalent json response object.

```
function madeAjaxCall(){ $.ajax({ type: "post", url: "jobs", cache: false,  data:{key:value;key:value}, success: function(response){ //user your data for view }, error: function(){    alert('Error while request..'); } }); } -
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you use the @Responsebody annotation NimChimpsky mentioned, the value of xmlhttpReq.responseText would be a JSON encoded string. Take a look at this post which explains how to parse a JSON string:
[Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)